# Reversi/Othello evaluation function

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I've written my own Reversi player, based on the MiniMax algorithm, with Alpha-Beta pruning, but in the first 10 moves my evaluation function is too slow. I need a good early-game evaluation function.

I'm trying to do it with this matrix (corresponding to the board) which determines how favourable that square is to have:

```
   { 30, -25, 10, 5, 5, 10, -25,  30,},
   {-25, -25,  1, 1, 1,  1, -25, -25,},
   { 10,   1,  5, 2, 2,  5,   1,  10,},
   {  5,   1,  2, 1, 1,  2,   1,   5,},
   {  5,   1,  2, 1, 1,  2,   1,   5,},
   { 10,   1,  5, 2, 2,  5,   1,  10,},
   {-25, -25,  1, 1, 1,  1, -25, -25,},
   { 30, -25, 10, 5, 5, 10, -25,  30,},};
```

But it doesn't work well.

Have you even written an early-game evaluation function for Reversi?

Comment: How many possible situations are in these 10 first movements? I would write a variation of your program that tries all of them, analizes with your algorithm and selects the best move. Then, store these values in your program.

Comment: first move > 3^64 with end-game stones counter evaluation.

Comment: How many different boards you can have in 10 moves? Keep in mind that by symmetry the real number will be 1/4 of those.